# undefined reference to function at run time after strip-ing the binary/so

Tags: embedded-linux, strip, linux-toolchain

Problem : After compiling and strip-ing the binary,  at runtime i get "undefined reference".

So while packaging, in the make-file i have tried adding "nostrip" at the end corresponding to that binary and it works fine. i. e. if i don't strip, it works.  I'm using wind-river tool chain. I think it has something to do with the way I'm compiling or linking.

The tools gcc,  ld,  strip etc are all from the same tool chain.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question is hard to answer as it stands.  It would be helpful to see the command line options passed to the tools.  Be aware that stripping a application `.so` assumes that none of the things that binary links to rely on symbols in the binary (circular symbol references).   This would often be the result of a poor design, but could also occur if your application programmatically links further models (e.g. plug-ins).

Comment: Thanks marco for the response. I managed to figure it out. The issue was, there were some environment variables in the make file which was making it to use the incorrect strip utility i.e. it was using the monta-vista strip utility instead of wind-river.

Answer (score 0):

Update

Solution : The issue was, there were some environment variables in the Makefile which was making it to use the incorrect strip utility i.e. it was using the monta-vista strip utility instead of wind-river.